How polite is the sentence "Вы не скажете, где лифт?" which is asked using negation?

Presently I am learning Russian & I am at Beginner level. I have seen this sentence in a book.

Вы не скажете, где лифт

Initially I thought that it was a printing mistake and it should be like

Вы скажете, где лифт?

Or it should be translated as "Won't you tell where the lift is?"
Later I put the sentence in google translator, it is translating it as "Can you tell where the lift is".
Then I realised that sentence is right. So I asked Copilot (Chat GPT) about it, it says it is one of the polite ways of asking.
My doubt is how often Natives use such sentences using negation for asking or requesting in spoken Russian? and What is the level of politeness in this sentence?

In Russian this question has no emotion whatsoever. It has nothing to do with politeness. English equivalent would be "Can you tell me there the elevator is?"


My doubt is how often Natives use such sentences using negation for asking or requesting in spoken Russian?

All the time.

What is the level of politeness in this sentence?

It's the baseline level of politeness expected from people asking for a favor.


– Не подскажете, какая из этих дам самая толковая? – как бы невзначай поинтересовался Колосенцев.
[Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]
Протиснувшись на лестничную площадку, спросила у курящего мужчины:   — Не скажете, это сорок седьмая квартира?   — Не знаю.
[Аркадий Мацанов. Горечь полыни на губах // «Ковчег», 2013]
Не порекомендуете ли нам скульптора, который вылепил бы женскую фигуру для одного спектакля?»
[В. И. Мухина. Воспоминания Веры Мухиной (1939-1940) // «Искусство», 1957]



You said "It is the baseline level of politeness". I understand it as it is the least polite sentence among all possibile polite sentences in this case. Did I get it right?

@SivaPrasad: I meant it more like "the expected level of politeness". More than than would probably be too unctuous, less than that too rude.

I'm a native Russian speaker (and I don't speak English well).
I will duplicate my comment, mostly using Chat GPT (but with some correction).
In Russian, "не" is a regular particle for polite forms. This may be unclear to Anglophones.
In our culture, we kind of ask "for the interlocutor," but we assume in advance that the request will be declined.
A less relevant example: in transport, we don't say "я выхожу" we ask: "вы выходите?" (implying that if the person is getting off, we don't need to switch places in the queue to the door). The phrase "вы не выходите?" has exactly the same meaning: we assume that it will be uncomfortable for the person if we hastily squeeze past them when the doors open.
I should also add that there are regional peculiarities.
In Moscow, such constructions are considered a waste of time. It's better to ask "Где лифт?" and thank the person after they respond (whatever the response).
However, the literary norm of polite communication constantly implies this "не" when we ask for advice:
"не подскажете, который час?"
"не знаете (случайно), где банк?"
"не согласитесь (ли) со мной поменяться?"
"сигаретой не поделитесь?"
This does not extend to replacing "нельзя" with "можно," but it is acceptable to use "нельзя ли":
"можно к вам подсесть?" ≈ "нельзя ли к вам подсесть?", BUT the construction with "нельзя ли" is perceived as more ingratiating (!).
By the way, we often ask whether something is present or absent using "нет"/"нет ли" (in rare cases "не найдётся"):
"нет ли поблизости аптеки?"
"у вас нет (чьего-либо) номера?"
"не найдётся зажигалки?"

Я нативный русскоязычный (и плохо говорю по-английски).
Простите, что пишу по-русски. Я продублирую комментарий через Chat GPT, но если вы изучаете русский, вам может быть интересно, как мы говорим о своём языке.
В русском языке "не" — регулярная частица для вежливых форм. Это может быть непонятно англофонам.
В нашей культуре мы спрашиваем как бы "за собеседника", но заранее допускаем, что в просьбе откажут.
Менее в тему пример: в транспорте мы не говорим "я выхожу", мы спрашиваем: "вы выходите?" (подразумевая, что если персона выходит, то нам не надо меняться местами в очереди к двери). Абсолютно то же значение имеет фраза "вы не выходите?": мы предполагаем, что персоне будет некомфортно, если мы будем спешно протискиваться мимо неё при открытии дверей.
Также добавлю, что есть региональные особенности.
В Москве такие конструкции считаются слишком большой тратой времени. Там лучше спросить "Где лифт?" и после ответа (любого) поблагодарить.
Но литературная норма вежливого общения постоянно подразумевает это "не", когда мы спрашиваем совета:
"не подскажете, который час?"
"не знаете (случайно), где банк?"
"не согласитесь (ли) со мной поменяться?"
"сигаретой не поделитесь?"
Это не распространяется на замену "нельзя" на "можно", но допустимо использовать "нельзя ли":
"можно к вам подсесть?" ≈ "нельзя ли к вам подсесть?", НО здесь конструкция с "нельзя ли" воспринимается как более заискивающая (!).
Кстати, мы чаще спрашиваем, есть или отсутствует ч/либо, через "нет"/"нет ли" (в редких случаях "не найдётся"):
"нет ли поблизости аптеки?"
"у вас нет (чьего-либо) номера?"
"не найдётся зажигалки?"

I think the root of misunderstanding is that the grammar book gave you wrong translations.
The phrase Could you tell me where the elevator is? translates to Russian as Могли бы вы сказать мне, где лифт? which means exactly what it means in English, does not have negation, and sounds quite polite in both languages. It sounds polite in both languages because you are asking whether the person is capable to help you or not rather than commanding him directly to give you help. In other words, you are asking to give you a favor.
In Russian, however, such phrase sounds too wordy when you speak to random person on the street, but is not impolite.
The phrase Вы не скажете, где лифт? means You will not tell me where the elevator is, will you? verbatim. Both phrases have negation, but the Russian version is shorter. I can't say for sure if the English variant sounds polite, but it has disguised request without the direct order too.
